# Core Audio on iOS 3.1.3 no audio

Tags: ios, core-audio, volume

I'm trying to use Core Audio to synthesize audio on first generation iOS devices and currently there is no audio being played.  My code works on iOS4/iPhone4.

I'm not using an AUGraph, just using `AudioComponentFindNext` to fetch the first RemoteIO component and setting `kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO` on it.

I've checked all the OSStatus codes and there isn't any errors being generated.

I've also verified that the callback buffer being filled, and that it's filled with valid sample data (used a square wave to test).

I'm out of ideas.  Help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here is my audio session code

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
float aBufferLength = 0.5; // In seconds
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareIOBufferDuration,
sizeof(aBufferLength), &aBufferLength);
AudioSessionSetActive(TRUE);
```

Comment: Is the volume turned up? (with the buttons)  Is an appropriate audio session enabled?

Comment: This is an iPod1, there are no volume buttons, but i can confirm that audio in another game(not mine) is at the proper levels.  I've edited the question with my audio session code.  Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was simply that my audio callback code is too slow for the device.  Apparently when there is a buffer underrun iOS just mutes the audio.